# Call Helpers From Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, view, zend-form, helper

I try this codes, but not works:

```
$this->getView()->translate("Name"); //not work
$this->_view->translate("Name"); //not work
$this->view->translate("Name"); //not work
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `Zend_View` is not injected into Zend_Form. So when you call `$this->view` or `$this->_view` it wont work, because there is nothing to return. Why `getHelper()` works? Because it fetches view via helper broker (and if your are using viewRenderer). Look below at the code:

```
// Zend/Form.php
public function getView()
{
    if (null === $this->_view) {
        require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php';
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $this->setView($viewRenderer->view);
    }

    return $this->_view;
}
```

This is reason why `$this->_view->translate()`  works if you call `getView()` before, because it's stored as protected property.
According to this, that code should work perfectly and works for me:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init() 
    {
        echo $this->getView()->translate('name'); //fires 'translate' view helper and translating value
        //below will also work, because you have view now in _view: getView() fetched it.
        echo $this->_view->translate("another thing");
    }
}
```

BTW. If your using translate helper to translate labels or names of fields, you don't have to. Will be enough, if you set translator object as a static property of `Zend_Form`, best in your bootstrap:

```
Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

And from that moment all fields names and labels will be translated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't no why, but when I add this function to my form, it work:

```
public function init() {
        $this->getView();
    }
```

this line works:

```
$this->_view->translate("Name");
```

Answer (score 2):

View is not injected into Zend_Form (don't ask me why, when it's required for rendering). You have to extend Zend_Form and inject view inside yourself. Other option is using FrontController->getInstance() > getStaticHelper > viewRenderer and recieve view from it.